# viewForZoomingInScrollView UIScrollView Background and Image not in sync

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am zooming on an image inside my scroll view.. But my scroll view has a background that I want to keep in sync with the foreground image.

This is what I have at the moment. I am wondering if I have to return bgImage in the viewForZoomingInScrollView method as well.. But Im just not really sure how or if its even possible to active.

This is what I have done below to get the image to zoom.. if anyone could help me figure out how to get the bg to scroll in sync also that would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"auckland-300.jpg"]];
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"249a-134206f1d00-1342071f5d9.ImgPlayerAUCKLAND.png"]];
    scrollView.contentSize = image.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:image];
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 31.0;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
    self.view = scrollView;    
}

#pragma Zooming

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean you want the background image to also zoom? What I would do is to use a `UIImageView` for the background image as well and put that image and also your `image` into a container view and return that in `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`. So something along these lines:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;

    backgroundImage = [[UIImageVIew alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"auckland-300.jpg"]];

    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"249a-134206f1d00-1342071f5d9.ImgPlayerAUCKLAND.png"]];

    // Note here you should size the container view appropriately and layout backgroundImage and image accordingly.
    containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:image.bounds];
    [containerView addSubview:backgroundImage];
    [containerView addSubview:image];

    scrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 31.0;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
    self.view = scrollView;    
}

#pragma Zooming

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return containerView;
}
```

Comment: I see what your doing there.. however I have an error on the line where you initialize the containerView that I have never had before "containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:image.frame.size];" The error reads Sending 'CGSize'(aka Struct 'CGSize') to a parameter of incompatible type 'CGRect'(aka Struct 'CGRect')

Comment: I changed it to this
containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,601,601)];

I suppose there would be a better way.... but I don't know about it... yet :) thanks for you help it worked perfectly

Comment: @C.Johns whoops yes sorry that was a typo. I've fixed it. Note my comment in the code though - you will need to set the frame, etc as per what you want. Sounds like you've got it though now.

Comment: '[scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];' resolves my issue, thanks!